# How can I make sure I am doing my exercises right?

Tags: workout

Specifically when I am doing dumbbell deadlifts and dumbbell squats, I have a feeling that I may not be doing the exercises correctly or may even be doing them in a harmful manner.

I've watched youtube videos to get instruction, but am still somewhat unsure.

For example when doing my dumbbell deadlifts, I keep my legs straight but feel that perhaps my back and/or legs bend more than they should, when I should probably be keeping my back straight.

Likewise when trying to do dumbbell squats I think my arms flex more than they perhaps should.

How can I make sure I am doing the exercises in a way that I am getting a benefit and not harming myself?

Comment: Related: [How to ensure you use the right technique when learning from a book?](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4354/how-to-ensure-you-use-the-right-technique-when-learning-from-a-book)

Answer (score 3):

You can take a video of yourself and link to it in an internet forum (here, even) or have a friend watch your form.

Don't try to do your lifts in front of a mirror to check your form. Just having the mirror there will affect your form. You'll end up looking up or sideways when you otherwise wouldn't be.

Answer (score 0):

**Some Help**

---

I normally just take a few pic's before hand, then up date them every few weeks.

Also make a planer or a training table with your weights and body body measurements and when working out you should feel it, if you don't feel anything then your not doing it right, like they say,

"No Pain No Gain!".

*I hope this helps.*